# Splitting a single string to multiple individual variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page in php in which there is a roll number field that will be retrieved from the database
like "$rollno"

now the problem is that i want to split The "$rollno" into individual character and store them in individual arrays.

Like if the roll no is 204cs10001

i want 2 to assigned to a variable
and 0 to a variable
and 4 to a variable
and c to a variable
and s to a variable
and so on till the last

and i have to use  the "c" and "s" variable for some comparison

Please help me out

Comment: why the java tag then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `str_split` in php to split character from string

```
$str = "Hello world";
$char_arry = str_split($str);
```

Then you will get

```
    Array
(
    [0] => H
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
    [5] =>
    [6] => w
    [7] => o
    [8] => r
    [9] => l
    [10] => d

)
```

Comment: plz more specific i am new

Comment: and i want to add each single character to different variables

Comment: and then how do i use the array to compare in a if statment

Comment: like IF($array0 == h && $array1 == e) {do something }

Comment: like,
if($array[0] == 'h' && $array[1] =='e') {/*do something */ }

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay Hardia